# ?wprptest=0, 1, 2, 3 ect at the end of all my URLs in google analytics

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

So I just received in about 20 minutes time 8000 hits on my site. I was watching this is google analytics real time.

All of the sudden, a page with 100 or so people on it, had a string appear at the end of the url like this.

website.com/page?wprptest=0  ( 100 active users )

I thought it was strange, then all the sudden it kind of went nuts, and i had 5 or 6 versions of the same page with different strings, like this...

website.com/page?wprptest=0  ( 100 active users )
website.com/page?wprptest=1  ( 80 active users )
website.com/page?wprptest=2  ( 20 active users )
website.com/page?wprptest=3  ( 23 active users )
website.com/page?wprptest=4  ( 43 active users )

Im running wordpress, and havent made any changes recently. I use Yoast SEO, W3 Total Cache, and cloudflare. I keep racking my brain but can't figure out where these came from. Anyone have any ideas? During this strange occurrence, I also received about 3x as much traffic as I normally do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with twitter/retweet of your link. That explain why yout traffic was increased.

I'm sorry i couldn't comment instead of awnsering it, because i can't tell you why, how, or where it started, but i can say that if you google `?wprptest=0` (as you probably did) you'll get only twitter results.
 The few non-twitter results are from posts that had their links copied from some tweet. You have any specific sharing plugin you use?

Comment: ok, now I can comment ¬¬ sorry i would have commented your question, but there's no comment link there

Comment: That makes sense, but when i googled it I couldn't find anything. Yes i use a sharing plugin. ShareThis

Answer (score 0):

This comes with wordpress related post plugin and they seem to use it for testing there related posts on mobile phone and devices. They do that to improve the related post they show on you page and for tracking traffic I guess.
It seems to be good so don't worry. So, that you get 3x more traffic shows that it's working very good for you. For me it keeps the people on the website up to 15 pages a visit.
If you don't like it, you can just change the plugin.